# A pure python equivalent of A[R][:,R]

Tags: python

I want to perform the equivalent of the `numpy`

```
A[R][:,R]
```

but in pure python. As an example:

`A = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]]` and

`R = [1, 2, 2]`

the output should be:

```
[[2, 3, 3],[3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4]]
```

Is there a nice way to do that in pure python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that would be `[[A[i][k] for k in R] for i in R]`

```
>>> A = [[0, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]] ; R = [1, 2, 2]

>>> np.array(A)[R][:,R]
array([[2, 3, 3],
       [3, 4, 4],
       [3, 4, 4]])

>>> [[A[i][k] for k in R] for i in R]
[[2, 3, 3], [3, 4, 4], [3, 4, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you! Simple in the end.

Answer (score 2):

The closest built-in ability to numpy's "indexing with a list" is `operator.itemgetter()` with multiple parameters:

```
>>> import operator
>>> g = operator.itemgetter(*R)
>>> [g(row) for row in g(A)]
[(2, 3, 3), (3, 4, 4), (3, 4, 4)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know about itemgetter.